# How to texture paint low poly model with normal applied

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I have a high poly model and a low poly model and baked a normal map from high poly to low poly. Now, I am wanting to texture paint the low poly model but am having diffculties because when I enter texture paint mode, I am only able to see the low poly model without the normal map. This makes it hard to properly texture paint the model.

Is there anyway I can do this so that when I texture paint, I am able to see the cracks, crevices, etc. from the normal map? I am using Blender 2.82.

Comment: Is it possible to paint the high poly object and bake down to the low poly, or is it a dyntopo sculpt that is too hard to set up for paint?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly the same problem as you and fortunately I found the solution.

What you need to do is to apply the texture you're painting to the low poly model.

To apply the texture to the model, just go to the shading tab and create a 'Image Texture' node. Select the texture you're painting and finally plug the color to the base color of Principal Node.
In the end, you will get something like this:

[image]

Don't forget to select 'lookdev' mode in order you can see the texture and the normal map while painting.